# current Flask app is not registered with this 'SQLAlchemy' instanceDid you forget to call 'init_app' or did you create multiple SQLAlchemy instances?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

`app.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template, redirect, flash, url_for, session

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

import hashlib

import string

import random

app = Flask(__name__)
app.template_folder = 'C:\\Users\\AloneWasser\\Desktop\\21\\templates'

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///C:\\Users\\AloneWasser\\Desktop\\21\\instance\\data.db'

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'C:\\Users\\AloneWasser\\Desktop\\21\\'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from project.models import *
```

`models.py`:

```py
from project.app import db

from datetime import datetime
```

Ошибка такова:

> RuntimeError: The current Flask app is not registered with this 'SQLAlchemy' instance. Did you forget to call 'init_app', or did you create multiple 'SQLAlchemy' instances?

Что делать с этим? Добавляя `init_app` выскакивает все та же ошибка, как фиксить?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `Flask(__name__)` вместо Flask(name)